# VSCode showing two color decorators instead of one

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, colors

I tried asking this on the VSCode subreddit and have had no replies so I'm hoping someone here will be able to help.

My VScode shows two color decorators instead of one, as normal.

Screenshot of the issue at hand: [image: Screenshot of the issue at hand]

I've tried disabling and re-enabling both the regular color decorator settings and the ones for Tailwind, and nothing has worked. I even enabled the setting manually in the JSON settings file and the issue persists.

I'm wondering if this could be another extension messing with this or if there is something I could try that someone else has found useful.

Here are the extensions I have installed as from the output of VSCode itself:

```
 1 adpyke.codesnap
  2 alefragnani.Bookmarks
  3 apollographql.vscode-apollo
  4 bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss
  5 dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets
  6 eamodio.gitlens
  7 esbenp.prettier-vscode
  8 formulahendry.auto-close-tag
  9 formulahendry.auto-rename-tag
 10 glenn2223.live-sass
 11 heybourn.headwind
 12 marlosirapuan.nord-deep
 13 miguelsolorio.fluent-icons
 14 mikestead.dotenv
 15 mkaufman.HTMLHint
 16 ms-azuretools.vscode-docker
 17 ms-python.python
 18 ms-python.vscode-pylance
 19 ms-toolsai.jupyter
 20 ms-toolsai.jupyter-keymap
 21 ms-toolsai.jupyter-renderers
 22 ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare
 23 ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-audio
 24 ms-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack
 25 octref.vetur
 26 PKief.material-icon-theme
 27 PKief.material-product-icons
 28 pomber.git-file-history
 29 ritwickdey.LiveServer
 30 Shan.code-settings-sync
 31 streetsidesoftware.code-spell-checker
 32 techer.open-in-browser
 33 Tobermory.es6-string-html
 34 usernamehw.errorlens
 35 vscodevim.vim
 36 Vue.volar
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you should delete each extension and check again to see if that's the issue?

Comment: Do you mean deleting and re-installing them one by one or deleting all of them and re-installing one by one to see if there is one at fault?

Comment: you can disable all of them and restart VSC, see if you have only 1 color decorator. Then enable them one by one, or use extension bisect

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that and then see what extension bisect is as I'm not familiar with that yet.

Comment: Turns out Vetur is the extension responsible for this. It's recommended I use this by my workplace as I work with Vue and I don't think this is expected behavior, but I didn't manage to fix it by uninstalling, restarting VSCode and re-installing Vetur. Documentation for Vetur doesn't seem to have an option about this I can toggle either. If anyone has any ideas about this I'm all ears. EDIT: It only happens within the <style> tag of a Vue component, if that helps.

Comment: Ended up being a conflict with another Vue plugin. Thanks for the suggestions, will carry them with me in the future.

Answer (score 0):

the inline colorful box next to the hex code is called `color picker`.

I think that the double picker shows up because you have both `Vetur` and `Volar` extensions running simultaneously.

> That fixes the issue. I had both Volar and Vetur extensions running.
> Removing Vetur (meant for vue2) removed the extra color picker. If
> possible, the extension author of Vetur could be asked to put up a
> deprecated or "use this Volar instead" info in their extension
> details. Sorry for the hassle. ❤️ VSCode

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/156544

Try disabling Volar - that did it for me.

If that doesn't work, try searching `color picker` in your VS Code settings to see if there are any options that may cause this behavior.

Cheers